# How do I change the version number of my custom Liferay portlet?

Tags: version-control, liferay, portlet

I am referring to the Installed Version column in the Control Panel > Server > Update Manager table.  Curerntly, it displays "unknown" for my custom portlet.  I want to set it to a specific value, say 1, for my first official build then increment it in subsequent builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change the Portlet Version number in the `liferay-plugin-package.properties` file which is in the `your-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF`.

I would suggest in future, you also post what version of Liferay you're using.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean Module Version (module-incremental-version in Source view)?

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant! Give it a go and see if it works! :)